# Determine the number of 6 digit positive integers such that at least one pair of consecutive digits differs by an odd number.

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I noticed that for an odd digit, then there are 4 choices for an even digit. For an  even digit, there are 5 choices for an odd digit. 
There are 5 locations possible in the integer.
What would be a good approach here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look for examples of $6$-digit integers where consecutive digits *never* differ by an odd number.

Comment: Each digit is odd or each digit is even. Where should I go from here?

Comment: Count all possibilities for these.  You should find that's pretty easy.

Comment: There are $10^6$ possibilities (10 digits including 0 to be placed in 6 positions) subtracted by $4^7$ for all even digits (including 0) subtracted by $4^7$ for all odd digits (including 0). Is that it? I am just learning the topic so thank you for the help.